# ASP.NET Core/5/6 - When exactly does a "Scoped Service" get disposed?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core/5/6 you can register a "Scoped Service" with the `ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped()` method.

In the Microsoft .NET Article *Dependency injection in .NET*, it states:

> In apps that process requests, scoped services are disposed at the end of the request. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped

Is their definition of "end of the request" **before** or **after** the response (including headers) has been sent?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer: after**

After running a test, it looks like scoped services are disposed **after** the response has finished sending. This is unfortunate, because if the response is a large file, it may take a few seconds to finish sending to the client, and the service will be unnecessarily kept alive (undisposed) that whole time. It would be better if scoped services were disposed **before** the response begins sending.

Anyway, here's the test I made.

First I created a test `IDisposable` class that writes to the console whenever it is instantiated and disposed:

```
public sealed class DisposableTest : IDisposable
{
    public DisposableTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("//////////////////// Created");
    }
    private bool Disposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!Disposed)
        {
            Disposed = true;
            Console.WriteLine("//////////////////// Disposed");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added the scoped service in Program.cs (for ASP.NET 6):

```
services.AddScoped<DisposableTest>();
```

Next I added some middleware to write to the console whenever the `Response.OnStarting()` and `Response.OnCompleted()` events were run:

```
app.Use(async delegate (HttpContext Context, Func<Task> Next)
{
    Context.Response.OnStarting(delegate ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("//////////////////// Response Started");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    Context.Response.OnCompleted(delegate ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("//////////////////// Response Completed");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    await Next();
});
```

Lastly I added the service to the constructor of HomeController so it gets accessed:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(DisposableTest TheTest) { }
    public IActionResult Index() { return View(); }
}
```

After visiting the path `/home/index`, the IIS Express console showed the following:

[image]

It looks like the service is disposed after the response finishes sending.

Comment: You can access the scoped service AFTER the response has been sent, for instance `HttpResponse.OnCompleted` so it MUST be disposed after the response has been sent!